# SpriteKit position confusion

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

In learning SpriteKit so I'm making a scene with 1 buttons.  I do not understand the way positions work.  What I read was that 0,0 was the bottom left corner and the default anchor point is in the middle of each button `(0.5,0.5)`. The scene is `scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill`. If I write:

```
    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(self.playButton.size.width/2,CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(self.playButton)
```

I get what is in the screenshot below.
If I set the `playbutton.position.x` to be `self.playbutton.size.width/2` then I would assume it would be on the left edge of the screen. Not weirdly somewhat off the screen. I've read the documentation about size for a couple of days now and I still can't seem to understand it. I've also explicitly set:

```
    self.size.width = 768
    self.size.height = 1024
```

Meaning the scene `size` `width` and `height`. Also I have "Use Auto Layout" in the main storyboard checked.

[image]

Comment: updated question tag with "sprite-kit" so that it will be noticed quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your scene's scale mode to `.AspectFit` you'll be able to quickly see what the problem is. The resolution you're setting for your scene is a completely different aspect ratio from that of your device. In fact, when I answered your last question, I assumed that your usage of the 768x1024 resolution meant that you were developing for an iPad, for which this is the correct resolution.

On an iPhone with a 4 inch screen, you should be setting the scene's size to be 320x568, and 320x480 for 3.5 inch screens. This can however be simplified by adding this line to the creating of your scene in your view controller. It will set the scene's size to the size of the view controller's view.

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Comment: Even easier: Set the scene's `scaleMode` to `SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill` – this way, it'll always have the same size as the view.